# How to use BITMAPV5HEADER with CreateDIBitmap function

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm trying to use a [`BITMAPV5HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183381.aspx) to create a bitmap that has the alpha channel:

```
BITMAPV5HEADER bi;
bi.bV5Size = sizeof(BITMAPV5HEADER);
bi.bV5Width = width;
bi.bV5Height = -height;
bi.bV5Planes = 1;
bi.bV5BitCount = 32;
bi.bV5Compression = BI_RGB;
bi.bV5SizeImage = 0;
bi.bV5XPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.bV5YPelsPerMeter = 0;
bi.bV5ClrUsed = 0;
bi.bV5ClrImportant = 0;
bi.bV5AlphaMask = 0x000000FF;
bi.bV5RedMask = 0x0000FF00;
bi.bV5GreenMask = 0x00FF0000;
bi.bV5BlueMask = 0xFF000000;
bi.bV5CSType = LCS_sRGB;
bi.bV5Endpoints = CIEXYZTRIPLE();
bi.bV5GammaRed = 0;
bi.bV5GammaGreen = 0;
bi.bV5GammaBlue = 0;
bi.bV5Intent = LCS_GM_IMAGES;
bi.bV5ProfileData = 0;
bi.bV5ProfileSize = 0;
bi.bV5Reserved = 0;

*hBmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, (BITMAPINFOHEADER *) &bi, CBM_INIT, data, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

But I'm unsure if the type-cast is correct. The [`CreateDIBitmap()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183491.aspx) is unclear, because in the field definition it says:

> *In* const BITMAPINFOHEADER *lpbmih,

and in the description:

> lpbmih [in]
>   A pointer to a bitmap information header structure, BITMAPV5HEADER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the type-casts are fine.

The [`BITMAPV5HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183381.aspx) documentation states:

> The `BITMAPV5HEADER` structure is the bitmap information header file. **It is an extended version of the [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376.aspx) structure.**

The first 11 fields of `BITMAPV5HEADER` match the fields in `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.  As such, you can safely pass in a type-casted `BITMAPV5HEADER*` pointer to the `lpbmih` parameter where a `BITMAPINFOHEADER*` pointer is expected.

The `lpbmi` parameter, on the other hand, is another story.  It is expecting a `BITMAPINFO*` pointer, but you are giving it a type-casted `BITMAPV5HEADER*` pointer instead.  Technically, a `BITMAPV5HEADER` is not an extension of `BITMAPINFO`, so you should be passing in a separate `BITMAPINFO` variable instead of your `BITMAPV5HEADER` variable.

However, `BITMAPINFO` starts with a `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, so the first 11 fields of `BITMAPV5HEADER` will satisfy the `BITMAPINFO::bmiHeader` field.  And you are setting the header's `biBitCount` field to 32 and `biCompression` field to `BI_RGB`, so there is no color table used, so `CreateDIBitmap()` will not try to access the `BITMAPINFO::bmiColors` field and end up reading your `BITMAPV5HEADER`'s alpha/gamma fields as RGB values.  So in this particular configuration, passing a type-casted `BITMAPV5HEADER*` pointer to the `lpbmi` parameter where a `BITMAPINFO*` pointer is expected is also "safe".